# Recursive function in Lisp

Tags: lisp, conjunctive-normal-form

I have to build a function which determines if I have a conjunction of well-formed formulas built in this way :

cong ::= '(' and wff wff ...')'

Let's suppose I have the code which determines if a formula is wff. The function must first check if the first element of the list is `'and`  and then check recursively the rest of the sublists if they are wff. Note that  `p` is also a wff so it doesn't neccessarily have to be a sublist.

Example : `(and (or a b v) (and a b d) m n)`

Here's what I tried which doesn't work for me :

```
(defun cong (fbf)
    (and (eq (first fbf) 'and )
        (reduce (lambda (x y) (and x y))
            (mapcar #'wff (rest fbf)))))
```

Comment: What does it do when you run it?

Comment: CL-USER 27 : 7 > (cong '(and a b c d))                              Error: Cannot take CAR of A.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a working `wff` predicate, your code will work. For example, using `numberp` as the predicate:

```
(defun cong (fbf)
  (and (eq (first fbf) 'and)
       (reduce (lambda (x y) (and x y))
               (mapcar #'numberp (rest fbf)))))
```

Works fine:

```
CL-USER> (cong '(and 1 2 3 4 5))
T
CL-USER> (cong '(and 1 2 3 4 foo))
NIL
CL-USER> (cong '(1 2 3 4))
NIL
```

Note, that this can be done more easily:

```
(defun cong (fbf)
  (and (eq (first fbf) 'and)
       (every #'wff (cdr fbf))))
```

Also, note that in CL, by convention, predicates usually should end in `p`.

So, your, given your comment above, your problem is the `wff` predicate, which doesn't seem to work for atoms. Since you mentioned that `p` satisfies `wff`, that predicate is plain wrong, but if you *have* to use it (assuming this is some kind of homework), just check if the element at hand is a cons:

```
(defun cong (fbf)
  (and (eq (first fbf) 'and)
       (every #'wff (remove-if-not #'consp (cdr fbf)))))
```

This assumes that every atom satisfies `wff`. Thus, they won't change the outcome of a conjunction and can be dropped. Otherwise, you'd have to write another predicate to check for atoms satisfying `wff` or, which would be the right thing to do, fix `wff` in the first place.

Also, note that none of this really involves recursion, since you're only asking how to apply a predicate to a list and take the conjunction of the results.

Comment: Well, I don't get it how wff can be wrong. That predicate should test if a formulae is well formed and is based on calling other functions. Here how it is defined: http://pastebin.com/VMDExFt1                        and here's the grammar it supports http://pastebin.com/jTpFw0bp

Comment: Well, in `fbf-fun`, `predicato` is evaluated after predicates that operate on lists. For example, `negazione` takes the `car` of its argument without previously checking whether it is a list at all. You'd have to check if the argument is a cons first – otherwise these tests will break.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand. What do you mean predicato is evaluated after predicates that operate on lists. I know that negazione takes the car of its argument without previously checking whether it is a list but when negazione fails, shouldn't the operator or in fbf-fun try to evaluate the remaining predicates like  cong, disg, etc ?

Comment: The thing is that this is *not* ML-style pattern matching. The code for `negazione` will be run, whether its argument is a list or not, thus it will try taking the `car` of an atom, if that was its argument. Applying `car` to an atom, however, will signal an unhandled `type-error`. Your predicate never returns and thus the other `or` branches will not execute.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe you should take the time to read up on a few Lisp basics again. On the one hand your code looks ok, using `reduce`, `mapcar` and so on – on the other hand you seem to have a few problems with basic evaluation rules.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24392/discussion-between-ester-vojkollari-and-danlei)